# Работа с Api, передавать несколько значений типа int в один параметр с помощью вложенного json

Tags: php, laravel, api

Есть переменная **$riskIsn** которая **принимает значение по ключу 'riskIsn'**, ее **тип данных это INT**, мне надо дать клиенту возможно передавать туда значение типа,  **1234436565, 57658898,** т.е у него должна быть возможно передавать несколько значений типа int в одну переменную,  ну и я в свою очередь должен буду принять эти несколько значений в одном параметре, не совсем понял, как это реализовать, кто подскажет?

сказали сделать через вложенный json объект, но код не работает, тупо 0 попадает в поле riskIsn

```html
 

 $riskIsnArr = json_encode(array(
            "risks" => array(
                "riskIsn" => $data['riskIsn1'] ?? null,
                "riskIsn1" => $data['riskIsn2']?? null,
                "riskIsn2" => $data['riskIsn3'] ?? null
            ),));

    "riskIsn1": 456456654,
    "riskIsn2": 67556456654,
    "riskIsn3": 907556456654,
    "name": "BORIS"
```

Comment: Если Вы будете передавать в параметре `"riskIsn": 456456654, 756456456, 543543534`, то тип данных больше не будет INT. Вам нужно будет преобразовать массив значений в строку, которая будет иметь вид `'456456654, 756456456, 543543534'` в итоге и на бекенде Вам нужно будет обработать эти значения соответствующим образом. Либо передавайте массив в этом параметре. На бекенде в любом случае Вам придется преобразовывать это в массив.

Comment: @Simon      $riskIsn = $data['riskIsn'];  $riskIsnArr = explode(',' , $riskIsn); вот так?

Comment: Если будете передавать в виде строки, то да.

Comment: @Simon сказали так тоже можно, но лучше сделать через вложенный json объект, вот так это делается?   $riskIsnArr = json_encode(array(
                    "risk" => array(
                 "riskIsn" => $data['riskIsn'],
                 "riskIsn1" => $data['riskIsn1'],
                 "riskIsn2" => $data['riskIsn2']
            ),));   Если что $data это Request

Comment: Не проще просто передать массив тогда? `"riskIsn": [456456654, 67556456654, 907556456654]`